# Speaker on I2S Pins

Tags: pi-4, i2s

I would like to connect a speaker (small speaker like in Google Home Mini) to my Raspberry Pi 4B. I don't want to use the jack socket. I have read that using the I2S pins of the Pi would be a good option. After doing some research on the net, I'm no longer sure whether this is generally possible and what is required. I still have an LM386 amplifier lying around at home. I would possibly like to use it.

I hope someone can give me some clarity.

Many thanks in advance.
Regards,
Manuel

Comment: google `i2s sink`